# Aseret Yemei Teshuva as a "foreshadowing" for the rest of the year?

Tags: yom-kippur

Is there a concept of the Aseret yemei teshuva being a "foreshadowing" for the rest of the year? for exmple, if someone has a very bad ten days (say he is put in foreclosure cv"s) is this a sign that the rest of the year will be downhill? or alternatively, does it mean that he was punished during the 10 days so that he could have a kapparah on yom kippur and then a good rest of the year?

please sight sources if possible.

Gmar Chatimah Tova!

Comment: Yudi B, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question. Whether the two are linked or not, I hope your 10 Days are going well, and that you are sealed for a good 5771. We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking "register," above.

Answer (score 1):

One custom that may bear on this is the one to ask for "lekach" (honey cake) before Yom Kippur, where one of the reasons given for this is so that in case one was under a Heavenly decree to have to beg for alms during the coming year, then this symbolic "begging" should satisfy that. In other words, the idea as in your second alternative: a bad experience during the Ten Days is meant to forestall the same thing happening during the rest of the year, rather than (G-d forbid) being a prelude to more of the same.